# LexerNoViableAltException in Nextflow process with perl substitute

Tags: regex, perl, nextflow

I'm trying to run a perl one-liner to perform a substitution on a file but getting a `groovyjarjarantlr4.v4.runtime.LexerNoViableAltException` seemingly at the perl digit character.

My script block is:

```
script:
"""
perl -pi -e 's/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf "%.0f", $1/eg' myFile.txt
"""
```

When I run the process I get the error:

```
unknown recognition error type: groovyjarjarantlr4.v4.runtime.LexerNoViableAltException
ERROR ~ Module compilation error
- file : /home/ryan/pipelines/nf-18S-pipeline/./modules/qiime2_merge_feature_tables.nf
- cause: token recognition error at: 'd+\.' @ line 27, column 22.
       perl -pi -e 's/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf "%.0f", $1/eg' myFile.txt
                        ^

1 error
```

I've had no trouble with other perl one-liners in script blocks such as:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\t/,/g' myFile.txt
```

so I expected this to work. I've not found anything useful so far looking online.

Comment: Wich *Perl* version are you running? I didn't get this error, trying it out on *CygWin* with "perl 5, version 36, subversion 1 (v5.36.1) built for x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi". Also ok on Ubuntu "perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi".

Comment: How big is your text file?

Comment: @PatrickJanser I'm running 5.26.1 and the actual perl works fine just not within the script block of nextflow so it's more likely a groovy issue.

Comment: The problem is with nextflow attempting to interpolate the `\d` prematurely before executing perl.  You say that using `\t` works, but that's because `\t` is likely interpolating prematurely as a tab character and then still work in the regex.  One way to dodge but not fix this problem is to change `\d` into a character class `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using single-quote blocks instead?

```
script:
'''
perl -pi -e 's/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf "%.0f", $1/eg' myFile.txt
'''
```

Not sure, but the backslash escaping might still be needed,
according to
[this discussion](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/67).
Your other example may have worked because `\t` was replaced by
a tabulation character, probably not breaking the pattern.
So have a test with this one also :

```
script:
'''
perl -pi -e 's/(\\d+\\.\\d+)/sprintf "%.0f", $1/eg' myFile.txt
'''
```

According to the
[documentation](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-script)
, If you use double-quote blocks then
you have to escape `$1` with `\$1` if not it will be seen as a
*Nextflow* variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think a single backslash in a groovy string works as an escape character. You could try escaping your `\` to `\\`. Not entirely sure if this is the answer because I cannot test it on this machine.

Comment: Thanks @Pallie I had tried double backslash (I should have mentioned in the original post) but it didn't fix the issue. The other Perl one-liner I posted works within nextflow as written so it doesn't seem to be the slash but rather something to do with `\d` itself